# Upgrading xConnect from Sitecore 9.1.0 to 9.1.1 - Database Upgrade Script missing?

Tags: xconnect

I'm in the process of upgrading a Sitecore 9.1.0 instance to 9.1.1. The Sitecore upgrade itself is done, but I need to upgrade xConnect as well.

Following the [Sitecore 9.1.1 Upgrade Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/E85A3706FCE547CC9C5FEB686C88881D.ashx), it states:

Before you upgrade xConnect:

1. Download the packages for XP Single – Sitecore 9.1.1 rev. 002459 (WDP XP0
   packages).zip – and unpack the zip file.
   To upgrade xConnect, you need the following file:
   o Sitecore 9.1.1 rev. 002459 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip
2. Unpack the Sitecore 9.1.1 rev. 002459 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip file.
3. Unpack the Database Upgrade Script.zip file. It contains several database upgrade scripts including:

   - SXP_marketingautomation.sql
   - SXP_referencedata.sql
   - SXP_processing_pools.sql
   - SXP_collection.sql
   - SXP_collection_AE_Part1.sql
   - SXP_collection_AE_Part2.sql
   - SXP_collection_GrantPermissions.sql
   - SXP_processing_engine_tasks.sql
   - SXP_mongodb_collection.js

So I did. But the `Database Upgrade Script.zip` file is nowhere to be found. Either that or I'm missing something.

This is what I downloaded:

[image]

And this is what's in the mentioned `Sitecore 9.1.1 rev. 002459 (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip` archive (well some of it, but the `Database Upgrade Script.zip` isn't there, nor are the mentioned files):

[image]

Is the script missing, or is there somewhere else I should be looking for these upgrade scripts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to download [Configuration Files for Upgrade](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/4A8250945B1B4BFB99B29B56FEE05787.ashx).

You find the link in the Upgrade Options section of page:

https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/91/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_91_Update1.aspx

[image]

The configuration files zip contains **Database Upgrade Script.zip**

[image]

Inside the zip file you will find the sql files that you need:

[image]

Comment: That is a very confusing bit in the upgrade.

Comment: Yep, I totally agree.

Comment: I’m going to forward this to the docs team and Martina. See if we can get it written more clearly.

Comment: Yea that could definitely have been clearer. I guess - in retrospect - I should have found these files on my own, but the installation and upgrade guides are very specific and step-by-step-ish, so I tend to just follow them verbatim.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if the upgrade guides are version specific? I mean its such a hassle to figure out at which point you are standing.